# Sql Query to get the Full name from the table Employee Eliminating Null Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an EmpName Table.

`Select * from EmpName`

```
NameID FirstName MiddleName LastName
1       Sam         NULL      NULL
2       NULL        Todd      Tarzan
3       NULL        NULL      Sare
4       Ben         Parker    NULL
5       James       Nick      Nancy
```

Now I write the following query to get the fullname as

```
Select FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName 
As FullName from EmpName
```

But I am getting the following result -

```
FullName
   NULL
   NULL
   NULL
   NULL
James Nick Nancy
```

But I want the following result -

```
FullName
   Sam
Todd Tarzan
   Sare
Ben Parker
James Nick Nancy
```

Is it - `String` concat with `Null` returns the `Null` ?

How can I get the `FullName` whose `MiddleName` or `LastName` has the value Null

Comment: The syntax is SQL Server syntax, not MySQL.

Comment: Yes; `NULL + anything` is `NULL`.  Look at `ISNULL()`

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Yes, but during tagging, from the stackoverflow suggestion, it prompts to tag MySql to reach maximum number of views. I just follow the stackoverflow suggestion.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Not an exact duplicate since concatenating is only part of assembling the full name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you concatenate strings, `NULL` takes precedence.  So, use `COALESCE()`.  This is a pain with separators, but the following should do what you want:

```
Select ltrim(coalesce(' ' + FirstName, '') +
             coalesce(' ' + MiddleName, '') +
             coalesce(' ' + LastName)
            ) as FullName
From EmpName;
```

Answer (score 2):

when you try to concate string with **NULL** it always give null

```
Select isnull(FirstName,'') + ' ' + isnull(MiddleName,'') + ' ' + isnull(LastName,'') 
As FullName from EmpName
```

if you use sql server 2012 or later version

```
Select concat(FirstName,MiddleName,LastName) as FullName 
As FullName from EmpName
```

Comment: +1 Didn't know about [concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)  Still, it does not appear to add spaces between parts of the name. You  could use `rtrim(concat(Firstname + ' ', Middlename + ' ', LastName + ' '))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a MySQL String function such as CONCAT().

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('My', 'S', 'QL');
```

More information here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 0):

Issue about null Try this query

```
Select isnull(FirstName,'') + ' ' +isnull(MiddleName,'') + ' ' + isnull(LastName ,'')
As FullName from EmpName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE` to avoid `NULLS` in following:

```
SELECT LTRIM(
       COALESCE(FirstName, '')  + ' ' + 
       COALESCE(MiddleName, '') + ' ' + 
       COALESCE(LastName, '') 
            ) AS FullName 
FROM EmpName
```

Comment: This approach would name yourself as `Stanislovas DOUBLE SPACE Kalasnikovas`

Answer (score 0):

NULLs propagate through a concatenation expression, hence your results coming through as NULL

To achieve what you're after you'd need to use ISNULL OR COALESCE:-

```
Select ISNULL(FirstName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(MiddleName,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(LastName,'')
As FullName from EmpName
```

OR

```
Select COALESCE(FirstName,'') + ' ' + COALESCE(MiddleName,'') + ' ' + COALESCE(LastName,'')
    As FullName from EmpName
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add `null` to a string (or anything else), the result is `null`:

```
select  'a' + null
-->
null
```

You can use [`isnull` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188795.aspx) to provide an alternative value for `null` columns.  By adding `+ ' '` inside the `isnull` call, you only get the space if that part of the name is not empty:

```
select  rtrim(isnull(FirstName + ' ', '') +
            isnull(MiddleName + ' ', '') + 
            isnull(LastName + ' ', ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on database you are using,

-- SQL Server / Microsoft Access--

```
SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName As FullName FROM Employee
```

-- Oracle--

```
SELECT FirstName || ' ' || LastName As FullName FROM Employee
```

-- MySQL---

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) As FullName FROM Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this also:

```
DECLARE @FirstName VARCHAR(10) = '  John  '
DECLARE @MiddleName VARCHAR(10) = NULL-- '  David   '
DECLARE @LastName VARCHAR(10) = '    A    '
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @FullName = COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FirstName)), '') + 
                   COALESCE(' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@MiddleName)), '') + 
                   COALESCE(' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@LastName)), '')

SELECT @FullName AS [Name], LEN(@FullName) AS [Length]
```

**For your query**

```
SELECT
    FullName = COALESCE(LTRIM(RTRIM(FirstName)), '') + 
               COALESCE(' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(MiddleName)), '') + 
               COALESCE(' ' + LTRIM(RTRIM(LastName)), '')
FROM
    Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ISNULL(FIRSTNAME,'') + 
        (CASE WHEN ISNULL(FIRSTNAME,'') = '' THEN ISNULL(LEFT(MIDDLENAME,1),'') ELSE ' ' + ISNULL(LEFT(MIDDLENAME,1),'') END) + 
        (CASE WHEN ISNULL(FIRSTNAME+MIDDLENAME,'') = '' THEN LASTNAME WHEN Isnull(MiddleName,'') = '' THEN LASTNAME 
         ELSE ' ' + LASTNAME END) AS FullName 
FROM tblEmp
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation : [How do I write a good answer ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)